# Umbraco-only accessible path for Tasks?

Tags: asp.net, umbraco, umbraco6

I want to build an umbraco task at something like /task. But how can I make sure that only the server is able to access the path? As in, I don't want it to be available for any users.

Comment: How are you going to call the task? From a scheduled task in windows, or using some other method?